# Data Annotation validations are not applied from partial class metadata

Tags: entity-framework, validation, webforms, data-annotations

I'm working on an `ASP.NET Web Forms` application with `Entity Framework 5` and the `Database first` approach. I have a separate project for my data access layer where my entities are generated. In this project I have the directory `ModelPartials` that I use to apply my `Data Annotations`. For example, I have the `Client` entity created :

```
namespace DataAccessLayer
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        this.Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
        this.ClientHistories = new HashSet<ClientHistory>();
    }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //the class continues...
```

And then in my `ModelPartials` folder I have:

```
namespace DataAccessLayer.ModelPartials
{
[MetadataType(typeof(ClientMetaData))]
public partial class Client
{
}

public class ClientMetaData
{
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Some error")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Some error")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
}
```

and here comes the problem. In my `aspx` file I have to add the class to the `ItemType`. If I try to navigate to the partial class in `ModelPartials` like so :

```
ItemType="DataAccessLayer.ModelPartials.Client"
```

I get an error that this class doesn't contain definitions of the properties I use. If I change it to:

```
ItemType="DataAccessLayer.ModelPartials.ClientMetaData"
```

then my properties are recognized, but in my back end my `Update` method is expecting `Client` as an argument:

```
public void Update(Client client)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //more code...
```

and I don't think that I have to change it to `ClientMetaData`. The only way I can get it to work is when I apply the `DataAnnotations` directly into the auto created Entity, but this make useless the whole idea of using metadata and so on.

What am I missing here to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial classes must reside in the same namespace for the partial to work.

So in your case set the namespace to DataAccessLayer

The metada can be in a different namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the namespace manually and it works fine. Do you have any idea if just deleting the extra part from the namespace is fine or theres better way to do it?

Comment: Deleting the extra part, saving and recompile does the trick. Dont let VS change the namespace with thw intellisense helper thingie.